# Sharepoint: Using DocumentID to reference other workbooks

Tags: links

I have a group of 3 excel workbooks on sharepoint, which pull data from each other. NB there is no circular referencing here - Book 1 references Book 2, Book 2 references Book 3, Book 3 stands alone.

If I were to rename the folder these workbooks live in, or rename the workbooks, these links will be broken.

Is there a way to use DocumentID to ensure that these links are never broken? It seems like a logical use of the feature to me, but I can't work it out...

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score 0):

The DocumentID is a unique URL which has a pointer to the file. This reference will not work for you (because you're not pointing to the xlsx/xls file directly). With Office Online Server, there is the Durable Link concept which serves the purpose of a URL that doesn't change (DocIDs intent is different), but again it doesn't reference the xlsx/xls file directly, but rather through a query parameter.

Ultimately, no there isn't a good way to do this besides moving away from Excel references to a better technology (i.e. SQL).